# Changing qml style at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i've started to learn qt and qml and get to some trouble - i wanted to change style of qml file in runtime by getting value(style name) from combobox, i've found the solution and found this as a bug:
QTBUG-68567: Document how to change the style at run-time
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68567
But i have trouble with realization, started with similar change of QQmlEngine, main window appear for a few miliseconds and then disapper

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QString str;

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);


    engine.load(url);

    str = "ModernStyle";
    qDebug() << "1";

   if (str == "ModernStyle") {
        qDebug() << "2";
    engine.clearComponentCache(); //unload all QML
    engine.exit(0); //destroy any existing QQmlEngine instance(s)
    qDebug() << "3";
    qmlClearTypeRegistrations();  //call qmlClearTypeRegistrations()


    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Fusion"); //call QQuickStyle::setStyle()

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine; //and then re-load the QML content so that QQC2 types are re-registered with the new style

    //const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

}
    return app.exec();
}
```

This is just simple example, this app deploy and finishing with 0 code, that's mean nothing crush or something else, maybe someone have made already this and can help.
Another what i wanted to do but got too much errors, to create a new class what will be inherited by QGuiApplication and there ovverride exec() method, but haven't finished this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a new class, that will be main class of app, where will be as private variables declarated QGuiApplication, QQmlEngine and this class will have method that's reloading engine, where will be executed step by step instruction from this link https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68567

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing would show up is because you create a second instance of `QQmlApplicationEngine` inside an if-block which then gets destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope. Do you even need a second instance? You may be able to simply reuse the existing instance.

```
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    ...

    if (str == "ModernStyle") {
        engine.clearComponentCache(); //unload all QML
        engine.exit(0); //destroy any existing QQmlEngine instance(s)
        qmlClearTypeRegistrations();  //call qmlClearTypeRegistrations()

        QQuickStyle::setStyle("Fusion"); //call QQuickStyle::setStyle()

        // QQmlApplicationEngine engine; // <<-- Don't declare this here.
        engine.load(url);
    }
    
    return app.exec();
```

If it turns out you do need a second instance of `QQmlApplicationEngine`, then just make sure it is declared outside the if-block so it doesn't get destroyed right away.

Comment: I've wrote as you said, but now i got error

QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
As i understood it doesn't see my qml files, but if i would start as simple way it works

Comment: Ok, then try my second suggestion, which was to simply move the declaration of your second QQmlApplicationEngine instance outside of your if-block.

Comment: I've tryed, but it's again appers for few miliseconds and then disapper and finishing with code 0. i've also try to use sleep() but the window of app was empty, have you some other suggestions? I'm in dead end

Comment: how i can correctly destroy any existing QQmlEngine?